# In CiviMail reports, how do I enable "Add these contacts to Group" for user levels other than Admin?

Tags: civimail, groups, civireport

I want to enable other user levels to be able to add contacts to a Group based on a list of results in a CiviMail Report using 'Add these contacts to Group'.

For example, a CiviMail Bounces Report shows 99 "bouncing" (undeliverable) e-mails. I want other user levels besides Admin to be able to add them to a new Group called Bouncing E-mails - 20150410 Outreach Mailing.

As the Admin, I see 'Add these contacts to Group' as an option in the Bounces Report. But other user levels do not see that. I don't see a permission to change under Drupal user permissions.

I have already enabled the available choices for the desired user level already. The choices are: access CiviMail, access CiviMail subscribe/unsubscribe pages, delete in CiviMail and view public CiviMail content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joe - Did some snooping in the code, and currently 'administer Reports' is required to expose 'Add Contacts to Group' in any report. Of course 'view all contacts' or some ACL granting permission to a set of contacts is also required or report results will be empty.

I think 'administer Reports' is not the right requirement. 'edit all contacts' or an equivalent ACL allowing editing is required in the rest of the user interface to allow 'add to group' - so I think the same should be true in reports.

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16274

Comment: Dave thanks so much checking it out today